# how can i put the value of textbox into alertmessegebox javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, message

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCosttotal" Text="10" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

this is my javascript code

```
<script>

 function GetValue() {

            var result = document.getElementById('<%=txtCosttotal.ClientID%>');
            alert("Your Total Cost is " + result);            

        }
</script>
```

my vb code the txtitemcost and requestedqty the value is coming from database

```
      Dim icost2 As Double = 0
        icost2 = Val(txtItemCost.Text) * Val(Txtrequestedqty.Text)
        txtCosttotal.Text = icost2


 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, [GetType](), "displayalertmessage", "GetValue();", True)
```

the output

" Your Total Cost is [object HTMLinputElement] "

Comment: missing .value in your javascript for this line
var result = document.getElementById('<%=txtItemNumber.ClientID%>');

Comment: 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

now im getting this error

Answer (score 1):

Your function `document.getElementById('<%=txtItemNumber.ClientID%>')` returns the actual `input` element. If you want to get to the actual value you need to use property `value`:

```
function GetValue() {
    var result = document.getElementById('<%=txtItemNumber.ClientID%>').value;
    alert("Your Total Cost is " + result);
}
```

You can read more about [`value` property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp)

Comment: 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference I put .value and this is the out put

Comment: This means there is no such element on the page. Most likely the reason is that in your textbox you have ID `txtCosttotal`, but in your code you are trying to access `txtCosttotal`. Update one of them accordingly. By the way, is your JavaScript stored in the aspx file or in external file?

Comment: in aspx file ... 

when I click the accept button the function of  Dim icost2 As Double = 0
        icost2 = Val(txtItemCost.Text) * Val(Txtrequestedqty.Text)
        txtCosttotal.Text = icost2 will trigger .. and also the alertmessage .. probably this is the cause .. alert message cant get any value from txtCosttotal



how to configure this ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, [GetType](), "displayalertmessage", "GetValue();", True) 

if I put the alert message here maybe something might change

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve. Your initial question was why you don't see the value of an input field, however I don't understand what other parts have to do with this